# Gatsby get image folder with relative path from data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am making a Gatsby static website and I'm having trouble with GraphQL.

I am trying to query all images in a folder using GraphQL. My data has the path:

```
"images" : "./relimages/vila-franceza",
"cardimages" : "./relimages/main-page-card-images/vila-franceza.jpg",
```

Getting the **cardimages** image works properly. I can manipulate it with gatsby image however I want.

But when I query for **images** (which is a folder), I only get the path to the folder.

Here's my query:

```
query flagquery {
  allDataRoJson {
    edges {
      node {
        images
        cardimages {
          id
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              originalImg
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my query, images returns as a string. How can i instead get it to be queryable by graphQL to instead get an array of images with the childImageSharp property like in the case where i specify the one image.

Here's the output of the query in GraphiQL

```
{
  "data": {
    "allDataRoJson": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "images": "./relimages/vila-franceza",
            "cardimages": {
              "id": "2a1fca39-6192-5e09-b913-43c5bf48966f",
              "childImageSharp": {
                "fluid": {
                  "originalImg": "/static/30337f0e47a254b68d443be671031647/0a89a/vila-franceza.jpg"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "images": "./relimages/vila-franceza",
            "cardimages": {
              "id": "2a1fca39-6192-5e09-b913-43c5bf48966f",
              "childImageSharp": {
                "fluid": {
                  "originalImg": "/static/30337f0e47a254b68d443be671031647/0a89a/vila-franceza.jpg"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "images": "./relimages/vila-franceza",
            "cardimages": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure it is just a syntax error, maybe this should be `"images" : "src/relimages/vila-franceza",
"cardimages" : "src/relimages/main-page-card-images/vila-franceza.jpg",` or  `"images" : "static/relimages/vila-franceza",
"cardimages" : "stactic/relimages/main-page-card-images/vila-franceza.jpg,`

Comment: Hey nick, the syntax is fine, because it works. the problem is that it sees images as just a string instead of a folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want to get all the images in the "images" folder and output them on your page with gatsby-image, this is how I do it:

```js
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"
import Layout from "../components/layout"

export default ({ data }) => (
<Layout>
  {data.allFile.edges.map(({ node }, i) => (
    <Img
      key={i}
      fluid={node.childImageSharp.fluid}
      alt={node.name}
    />
  ))}
</Layout>
)

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allFile(
      filter: {
        extension: { regex: "/(jpg)|(png)|(tif)|(tiff)|(webp)|(jpeg)/" }
        absolutePath: { regex: "/images/" }
      }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          name
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 915, quality: 70) {
              aspectRatio
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

My images folder was located: `src/images`

Comment: My data has a path to a folder. i want all of the contents of that folder directly, like if i just pointed to an image. if my path is: data/images, i want an array of all the data/images/***